# Formatear porcentaje en C#

Tags: c#, formato

Estoy teniendo un pequeño problema con el formateo de números a porcentaje, tengo un `List<decimal>` que posee estos elementos

```
0.006250
0.010000
0.012500
0.016600
0.025000
0.050000
```

Pretendo obtener de retorno:

```
0,0625%
1%
1,25%
1,66%
2,5%
5%
```

Estoy intentando lo siguiente

```
NumberFormatInfo formato = new NumberFormatInfo();
formato.PercentDecimalDigits = 4;

numero.ToString("p",formato);
```

Pero de esta manera, estoy recibiendo lo siguiente:

```
0,06250%
1,00000%
1,25000%
1,66000%
2,50000%
5,00000%
```

¿Cuál sería la manera correcta de formatearlo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Logre solucionarlo gracias a la [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48779962/5213794) de [**laith**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/664389/laith).

La traduzco para que pueda serle de utilidad a alguien

```
double value1 .92;
double value2 .923;
string formatted1 = $"{value:0.#%}"; // "92%" 
string formatted2 = $"{value:0.#%}"; // "92.3%"
```

El símbolo `%` es la notación utilizada para multiplicar el número por `100` y agregar el símbolo de porcentaje.

Usar `P` es una notación más corta, pero `%` permite personalizar la salida

Por lo cual, el formateo del `string` es igual que siempre, pero sólo se le agrega el símbolo `%` al final.

Answer (score 1):

Usa el ToString  con p. Aqui te pongo ejemplo

```
decimal jose = 0.0125m;
Console.WriteLine(jose.ToString("p02"));
Console.WriteLine(jose.ToString("p01"));
Console.WriteLine(jose.ToString("p03"));
Console.WriteLine(jose.ToString("p0"));
```

Los resultados son así:

```
1.25%
1.3%
1.250%
1%
```

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte, JLOrdaz y bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el [recorrido del sitio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Hice una pequeña extensión que me es mas cómoda de usar, con los `string` literales, luego me es más dificil leer el código.

Lo dejo por si le es útil a alguien!

```
public static string ToStringP(this decimal s, string format)
{
    int n;
    if( ! format.ToUpper().Any(x => x != '#') ) 
    {
        var f = $"0:0.{new String('#', format.Count(x => x == '#'))}%";
        return string.Format("{" + f + "}", s);
    }
    else if ( int.TryParse(format,out n))
    {
        var f = $"0:0.{new String('#', n)}%";
        return string.Format("{" + f + "}", s);
    }           
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("Uso invalido de la extensión");
    }
}
```

Se usa cómo `decimal.ToStringP("#");` Con tantos `#` como decimales se necesite, o como `decimal.ToStringP("2")`, con el `2` representando también, la cantidad de decimales.